# Can I export and import Visual Studio 2010-extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am setting up Visual Studio 2010 on another computer and would like it to have the same extensions as the old installation. If possible it would be nice to just import a package of files or similar. Settings can be managed this way which is very useful but I was not able to find the same functionality for extensions.

TIA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You have two options.

First, you can do it on a per-user basis (for extensions that you've installed through the extension manager or by double-clicking on VSIXes).  For this, you:

1. Copy `%localappdata%\microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions` to the same directory on the new machine.
2. Open VS on the new machine, go to the extension manager, and Enable all the extensions.  By default, VS disables extensions that just appear in that directory but it didn't put there.

The second option is to install the extensions to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions`.  The upside is that you don't need to Enable them all by hand, but the downside is that you won't be able to update/remove them from within VS.

Comment: For anyone looking to do this with Visual Studio 2015, I can confirm that this method still works.

Answer (score 4):

This Visual Studio 2010 extension, [ExtensionSync](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbaf0ac9-fb7b-4fb3-b34d-ea2269276d3c), by Latish Sehgal, should make your day.

1. Open IDE1, install ExtensionSync.
2. Close IDE1, it should write the extension settings in an xml file (you can set/see the location in `Tools/Options/ExtensionSync`).
3. Open IDE2, install ExtensionSync, go to `Tools/Options/ExtensionSync` and specify the xml file directory or just write it down (caution: do not specify the same directory as the previous one as otherwise, when closing IDE2, it would overwrite the xml file you already have with an empty one).
4. Close IDE2, then copy/paste the xml file from the ExtensionSync directory for IDE1 into the directory for IDE2.
5. Open IDE2, go to `Tools/Extensions Manager`, once you see Restart Now, do it so that the extensions from IDE1 can finally appear as installed in IDE2.

By appropriately setting a common ExtensionSync directory using a service like [Dropbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbaf0ac9-fb7b-4fb3-b34d-ea2269276d3c) as cloud storage, you can also keep two environments in sync.