# How to export Visual Studio 2010 extensions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I export and import Visual Studio 2010-extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275323/can-i-export-and-import-visual-studio-2010-extensions)

I want to reinstall my Windows 7 and how can i export extensions from VS 2010 ? And after reinstaling import them?

Is it possible ?

I have lot of ext. will by easy way how to install them after VS reinstall.
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for exporting the installed extensions for Visual Studio.  The easiest way to approach this problem is to simply write down the list of extensions and reinstall them once you've got your machine up and running again.

One trick you could try is the following.  The binaries for **many** but not all extensions are stored under

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions

You could simply zip up that directory, save it somewhere, re-install windows + vs and then unzip the file on the new machine.  I do not know if that would work but it may be worth trying.

Comment: Thank you. This path is which i looked for

Comment: Aaaargh, once again I clicked "downvote" by accident on Friday, and didn't notice until Monday morning -- past the 48-hour deadline, so my vote is locked until the question is edited. Care to edit, so I can rectify my mistake?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis did you ever revert the downvote?

Comment: No, it still says "You last voted on this answer
Oct 21 '11 at 16:19
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited" when I try to upvote it.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis made a minor edit :)

Comment: This extension creates a script that will install all the extensions on a seperate machine.https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bede104c-8b57-4649-8777-b994b3b63abc